Proper setting up of a reproducible quarto output based on a custom R package
I have a simple data pipeline where the data and the functional code are stored in a custom R package hosted on Azure DevOps and the final outputs are produced by quarto documents pointing to specific branches of the package.
I struggling to find a proper way to connect the quarto documents to this package in order to download it only if changed. Here's my code in the first chunck of the quarto doc:
```{r setup}
#| include: false
#| cache: false
#| message: false
#| warning: false

c("git2r", "renv", "remotes") |> 
  sapply(\(x) {
    if (!requireNamespace(x, quietly = TRUE)) {
      install.packages(x)
    }
  })

renv::activate()

gitcred <- git2r::cred_user_pass(
  username="username",
  password="repo-specific-pass")

remotes::install_git(
  "https://my-azure-repo.com/_git",
  build_manual = FALSE, build_vignettes = FALSE,
  upgrade = FALSE,
  dependencies = TRUE,
  ref = "2024-04-29_ECCMID", credentials = gitcred)

renv::snapshot()
```#

This code works, but it reinstalls the package every time. What should I change to avoid this?
